# How to get the directory of launched wxwidgets application in mac?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, wxwidgets

I have C++ application built with the help of wxwidgets, I would like to know how can we find the application directory of the launched application, I figured that using wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath() I get application path in mac which is something like /library/application/abc.app/macos/contents.

All I need is to extract till /library/application, is there a way to do it in wxwidgets?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the application directory and what do you need it for? Using the existing `wxStandartPaths` methods should suffice for most of the cases.

Comment: I would like to load some bundle file which will be placed in the application directory. It need to need this path to provide the location to load the bundle file

Comment: Usually you don't put things directly in the bundle root but in some subdirectory. And `wxStandardPaths` gives you access to some of them, see e.g. `GetPluginsDir()` or `GetResourcesDir()`. Just put your file in the directory returned by either function.